# Why can't a Plot be rendered by Graphics if it's a member of a list?

Tags: graphics, warning-messages

I grabbed the code to render a gear from a Mathematica Demo, but I'm having difficulty reproducing the way it's to be used:

```
gear[{x_, y_}, n_] := ParametricPlot[{
    {x + (1 + 2 n) Cos[1.5708/n + theta] - Cos[1.5708/n + theta + 2 n theta], 
     y + (1 + 2 n) Sin[1.5708/n + theta] - Sin[1.5708/n + theta + 2 n theta]},   
    {x + (-1 + 2 n) Sin[1.5708 - 4.7124/n - theta] 
                  - Sin[4.7124 - 4.7124/n - theta + 2 n theta], 
     y + (-1 + 2 n) Cos[1.5708 - 4.7124/n - theta]
                  - Cos[4.7124 - 4.7124/n - theta + 2 n theta]}}, 
    {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotPoints -> 101, RegionFunction -> (SquareWave[n #3/6.2832] > 1*^-6 &), 
    Axes -> False]
```

Then

```
Graphics[gear[{0, 0}, 20]]
```

works as expected, but

```
Graphics[{Thick, gear[{0, 0}, 20]}]
```

generates the `Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive` error.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I would now like to be able to rotate my gears, e.g. `Rotate[gear[...],theta]`.  Unfortunately now `First` simply removes the `Rotate`.  Any suggestions for what will work in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gear` produces `Graphics` so there is not need to add another.

If you want to modify the content you have to take it out:

```
Graphics[{Thick, First@gear[{0, 0}, 20]}]
```

Your first example works because it seems `Graphics` by default flatten `Graphics[Graphics[`:

```
Nest[Graphics, Disk[], 5]
```

to only one.

But your second example is something different, `Graphics[{ ..., Graphics` and this is not correct syntax.

Comment: I would now like to be able to rotate my gears, e.g. `Rotate[gear[...],theta]`. Unfortunately now `First` only removes the `Rotate`. Any suggestions for what will work in this case?

Comment: @Keith like `Rotate[First@gear[], theta]`?

Answer (score 3):

Resetting `AbsoluteThickness` directly also works:

```
t=4;    
gear[{0, 0}, 20] /. AbsoluteThickness[z_] -> AbsoluteThickness[t]
```

[image]

Choose whatever `t` you wish, although too large a choice causes the two colors to overlap excessively.