# A plot with labeled points in one plotting command?

Tags: graphics

For my work, I am examining the values of a complex function as I vary the input according to a real parameter, and I want to both give the general plot and the plot of specific points, with labels (so one sees the direction of increase).

I knew from the documentation that `Point` and `Epilog` together allow you to label points on graphs; e.g.,

```
ourF[z_] := z^2;
parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]}
ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3 , 3}, 
 Epilog -> {{PointSize[Medium], 
    Point[Table[parts[ourF[ j + I/4]], {j, -3, 3}]]}}]
```

This produces:

[image: A plot with labeled points, just as in the documentation]

Looking at the answers to this site's [Question 1854](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/adding-labels-to-points-in-listplot) (especially Jacob Jurmain's), `Listplot` in newer versions of Mathematica has a `Labeled` option that labels the points in the `Listplot`.  Indeed, I can get what I want by making a `Plot` and `Listplot` separately and then `Show`ing them together.  e.g.

```
ourF[z_] := z^2;
parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]}
plotOne = ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3 , 3}];
plotTwo = ListPlot[Table[Labeled[parts[ourF[ j + I/4]],
     Row[{"x = ", j}], Right
     ], {j, -3, 3}]];
Show[plotOne, plotTwo]
```

which yields

[image: A plot with labeled points]

as required.

My first attempt, however, was to simply put the `ListPlot` in the `Epilog`, e.g.

```
ourF[z_] := z^2;
parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]}
ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3 , 3}, 
 Epilog -> {ListPlot[Table[Labeled[parts[ourF[ j + I/4]],
      Row[{"x = ", 13/10 + j/10}], Right
      ], {j, -3, 3}]]}]
```

This yields the error:

```
Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive.
```

I guess `ParametricPlot` calls `Graphics`, and `Listplot` is now calling `Graphics` inside the other `Graphics`, hence the issue.

I also tried putting `Labeled` in the `Point` variation, but `Point` doesn't know what to do with the label, and the error message becomes

```
Coordinate Labeled[{8.9375, -1.5}, Row[{"x = ", 1}], Right] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

---

**Q:** Is there any way of putting it all in one plotting command?

---

*P.S.:*  An answer in the vein of, "You have acceptable output, stop worrying about it" would also be reasonable.  I am new to Mathematica, but it seems to the newcomer as though Mathematica puts in one line what I would use 5-10 lines in MATLAB to set up, and [after having debugged] the fewest number of lines is the best.

Comment: Add `First` on `ListPlot`. Related: [73402](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73402/5478), because `Epilog` essentially accepts the same what `Graphics` does.

Comment: Are you satisfied with any of the answers here, or do they still leave issues unaddressed?  Please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/), or leave a comment indicating what needs to be done.  Also, consider [taking the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour), if you have not done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to show you can readily do this directly with graphics primitives:

```
ourF[z_] := z^2;
parts[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]}
ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3, 3},
    Epilog -> Table[{ {PointSize[.01], Red, Point@#},
        Text[Row[{"x = ", 13/10 + j/10}], #, {-2, 0}]} &@
        parts[ourF[j + I/4]], {j, -3, 3}],
          PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are five keystrokes (`[[1]]`) close to something that works (See also: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71997/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69940/125))

```
ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 30,
 Epilog -> ListPlot[Table[Labeled[parts[ourF[j + I/4]], Row[{"x = ", 13/10 + j/10}], Right], 
                    {j, -3, 3}]][[1]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `ParametricPlot[...][[1]]` as the `Epilog` setting in `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[Table[Labeled[parts[ourF[j + I/4]], Row[{"x = ", 13/10 + j/10}], Right], {j, -3, 3}], 
 Epilog -> ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3, 3}][[1]]]
```

**Update:** Using `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh`:

```
ParametricPlot[parts[ourF[x + I/4]], {x, -3, 3},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 500,
 BaseStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Blue}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Table[{Im[ourF[j + I/4]], 
            Text[Style[Row[{"x = ", 13/10 + j/10}], 12, Black], parts[ourF[j + I/4]], {-2, 0}]}, 
          {j, -3, 3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Text[] also has the reference point option after the position. It would make the lables not intersect the line - looks better.

Comment: @Alexey, excellent point, thank you.